# What is the use of -n while starting activity using adb shell am start command

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, adb, android-testing

We can able to launch activity using the following adb shell command.

```
adb shell am start -n <PackageName>/<ActivityName>
```

But some of apps the above command is not working, we need to remove "-n" option from the above command. Like following.

```
adb shell am start <PackageName>/<ActivityName>
```

What is the use of "-n" option? why sometimes we can not able to launch app using "-n" option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Specification for intent arguments](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#IntentSpec):

> -n component
>
> Specify the component name with package name prefix to create an explicit intent, such as com.example.app/.ExampleActivity.

Answer (score -3):

Short answer: **none**.

Because according to the [Android ADB Command Line Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html) there is no option `-n` for the activity manager. So there's no need to have that option there in the first place.